# Do migrated questions also migrate their score?

Tags: discussion

The question https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18277/is-this-pseudo-science-or-real-code-found-in-superstring was migrayed from Physics.SE. It also migrated its comments, two of which have a "-1" declaration. At this time the score of the question is -1. I am wondering if the score is the score from physics.SE or was it migrated with a score of 0 and then downvoted by our users?

If the former is the case, I think that question that are migrated should have their score reset, as different sites on the SE network vote on question for different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Migrated questions are migrated with their votes:

- [Reset votes on migrated questions is [status-declined]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions)
- See also [this](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/862/rejecting-incoming-migrations-with-bad-answers) which suggests that if old votes or migrated answers are a problem, then Skeptics moderators can close or re-ask the question.

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration) the score for questions with a negative score is reset.

Comment: To others as confused as I was: @Ilya's reference shows downvotes are removed. ChrisW's reference shows upvotes are retained.